# Hybris Commerce Server start up failed

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am beginner to Hybris, I am trying to go through Hybris commerce trails for customised B2B accelerator extension through modulegen.
After installing the B2B recipe,addons and running ant Initialize I started the server and tried to access the below link
https://powertools.local:9002/trainingstorefront/powertools/en/USD
but was not able to.

Could someone please let me know where I am going wrong.

Regards,
Farhan

Comment: Have you added this to your hosts file? `127.0.0.1 apparel-uk.local apparel-de.local electronics.local powertools.local` ?

Comment: yep, that sounds like the problem. Alternatively you can also append ?site=powertools to the first URL you open in a browser. That will set the base store for that brower's session and should work as well

Comment: Yes Alain, i have added 127.0.0.1 powertools.local entry in the hosts file. i even tried mapping it to localhost and then modified url to reflect localhost https://localhost:9002/trainingstorefront/powertools/en/USD accessing it from the browser, still was not able to hit the server. Also I tried accessing HAC,HMC using just https://localhost:9002/ and resp for HMC but no success. I will try what Sebastian is suggesting. Thanks for help guys!

Comment: I tried accessing using http://localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront?site=powertools&clear=true, but this navigates to HAC and on log in to HAC it shows 404 error.

Comment: When you go in hac->extension, do you see trainingstorefront extension? If so does the webroot is defined? Finally you have to check in the backoffice (or hmc) if the website exist (and have a url pattern). If it's not the case you problably missed extensions in localextensions.xml or maybe you do'nt have updated properly your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL looks incorrect. You can find the right URLs by going to https://localhost:9002/mcc/login.zul and logging in as admin. It will give you the links to all of the storefronts and services.